# Mypy complains about TestCase attributes set in setUpTestCase

Tags: python, django, testing, mypy

I have a project written in Django (Django 3.0, Python 3.8), using [django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs) to handle type annotations. Everything went fine until I wrote some tests:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.some_value = 'foo'
        cls.another_value = 'bar'

    def test_me(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(self.some_value, self.another_value)
```

When I run mypy, it raises '[attr-defined]' errors about the TestCase class attributes defined in `setUpTestData`:

```
 $ mypy --show-error-codes .
my_app/tests/test_something.py:6: error: "Type[TestSomething]" has no attribute "some_value"  [attr-defined]
my_app/tests/test_something.py:7: error: "Type[TestSomething]" has no attribute "another_value"  [attr-defined]
my_app/tests/test_something.py:10: error: error: "TestSomething" has no attribute "some_value"  [attr-defined]
my_app/tests/test_something.py:10: error: error: "TestSomething" has no attribute "another_value"  [attr-defined]
```

I cannot find any advice about type annotations in tests (even tests in general, not to mention Django or unittest tests specifically). I don't think I am using `setUpTestData` to do anything it is not supposed to do, so I wonder why nobody reported such issues before.

My main question is:

**How can I annotate this code to make mypy satisfied?**

A corollary question:
**Does it even make sense to add type annotations in tests? Maybe I should just configure mypy to ignore test modules?**

Here's the mypy.ini file - I would rather not change the settings to be more lenient:

```
[mypy]
plugins = mypy_django_plugin.main
python_version = 3.8
ignore_missing_imports = True
strict_optional = True
disallow_subclassing_any = False
disallow_any_generics = True
disallow_untyped_calls = True
disallow_incomplete_defs = True
check_untyped_defs = True
disallow_untyped_decorators = True
no_implicit_optional = True
warn_redundant_casts = True
warn_unused_ignores = true
warn_return_any = True

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = studio.settings

[mypy-*.migrations.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that the class does not declare those attributes "statically", so something like:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    some_value = None
    another_value = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.some_value = 'foo'
        cls.another_value = 'bar'

    def test_me(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(self.some_value, self.another_value)
```

should make the static code analyzer happy

Comment: Good point, this makes mypy happy indeed. However, I've got dozens of attributes created in a number of testcases, so it's not really feasible to declare them all like this. I was hoping to find a... less verbose? and maybe test-specific solution.

Comment: I think you have to dig into mypy settings in order to make it less strict then :P

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit safer way to satisfy the type checker, without setting a `None` value on the attributes:

```py
from typing import ClassVar

from django.test import TestCase

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    some_value: ClassVar[str]
    another_value: ClassVar[str]

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.some_value = 'foo'
        cls.another_value = 'bar'

    def test_me(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(self.some_value, self.another_value)
```

[[source]](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8723#issuecomment-665911420)

There is an open [mypy feature request](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8723) to support it natively.